# Why are some of my edits barely changed during review?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've edited a handful questions over at Stack Overflow out of actual interest in making things more clear or proper formatting, but I've noticed a strange phenomenon occurring lately. I've recently observed a few users changing my edits, but making no impactful changes. Examples include moving an embedded image's link one line up or down, changing a question's title capitalization, etc.

These users tend to have enough reputation to approve their own edits. Are they gaming the system, or am I just so new to Stack Exchange that there's something I don't know going on here?

Comment: If they have enough rep to "approve their own edits", they don't get any additional rep from doing so.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.. Any idea why it's happening though?

Comment: Because they like the edit you've made for the most part but feel more edits can be done. So they select "Improve Edit" on their review of your edit, which approves your edit then allows them to edit the question from the state your edit leaves the question in. For example, your [last edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12383270) was good! The reviewer approved it because it was a decent edit, but edited it further to make the image alt text descriptive. (This is helpful for users the image doesn't load for and for screen readers.)

Comment: @ZGski _"Any idea why it's happening though?"_ Sometimes higher rep users like to shorten the process of an edit review, and improve your edits to make them appearing in the post. I'm doing that sometimes preferred over approving another OPs edit and have to wait to apply mine.

Comment: When I am working the suggested edit queue, if I see an edit that's nearly perfect, except they forgot to do one thing, I'll usually just improve the edit. Just be glad that you're not getting rejected.

Comment: This editing of my question _about editing_ is starting to get out of hand..